# Canonical way to e2e test angular UI grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, angular-ui-grid

**The Story:**

Recently, our UI switched from custom tables to [Angular UI grid](http://ui-grid.info/) as it got stabilized and feature-rich.

The main Angular UI grid page claims to have "e2e testing integration", but we are having the hard time making this work.

From what we understand, what they meant under "e2e testing integration" is the two [helper files](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/403_end_to_end_testing): [`gridTestUtils`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/test/e2e/gridTestUtils.spec.js) and [`gridObjectTestUtils`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/test/e2e/gridObjectTestUtils.spec.js).

There are multiple problems with that:

- these two helper files are not a part of the `angular-ui-grid` module itself and are not available as a separate library which means we need to basically copy the *current* contents of both files and create them locally manually
- it looks like all the helper functions require a grid ID to be known beforehand, but our grids have auto-generated (by `angular-ui-grid` itself actually) ids and we locate the grids using other locators

On the other hand, the provided in these helper files methods like `resizeHeaderCell()`, `shiftClickHeaderCell()` are really handy and may save a lot of time  when it comes to testing.

**The Question:**

What is the canonical way to test angular UI grids and has anyone had any luck e2e-test-integrating with the library via the above-mentioned helper functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to copy the current contents of these files and create them locally manually. You can install ui-grid repository via npm: `npm install angular-ui/ui-grid`.