# end to end test - using ui-grid

Tags: protractor, angular-ui-grid, end-to-end

I am using ui-grid in my app, and I would like to select row in the grid - ie: programmaticly  checkbox a row.

I saw that there are is the file [gridTestUtils.spec.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/master/test/e2e/gridTestUtils.spec.js) in ui-grid/tests folder ,

I have copied it into my tests/lib folder.

Now how can I use it to select a row in my grid?

I hope you can help

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502815/canonical-way-to-e2e-test-angular-ui-grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to select a row element by first defining a page object as so:

```
'use strict';

var AngularPage = function () {

};

AngularPage.prototype = Object.create({}, {

    videoListGrid: { get: function () { return element(by.css('div[ui-grid="videoListGridOptions"]')); }},
    uiGridCell: { get: function () { return element(by.css('.ui-grid-cell')); }},

});

module.exports = AngularPage;
```

Now that these page objects are defined, here is the test:

```
var gridId = null;
var viewVideoPage = require('./../pages/viewVideo.page.js'); //define the page object
/**
 * make sure to bring in the gridTest utility library
   https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/test/e2e/gridTestUtils.spec.js 
 */

var gridUtils = require('./../lib/gridTestUtils.spec.js');


describe('MEP-1023 Test the Video Tags Feature for user MANAGER', function () {
    var page;

    beforeEach(function () {
        page = new viewVideoPage();
    });

    it('should get the grid id and checkbox the first row', function () {

        page = new videoListPage();

        expect(page.videoListGrid.isPresent()).toBe(true);
        //now get the gridId
        page.videoListGrid.getAttribute('class').then(
                function (classes) {
                    var classArr = classes.split(" ");
                    console.log(classArr.length);
                    _.each(classArr, function (theClass) {
                        //find the class that starts with grid, and grab the gridId which we can use to refer
                        //to the various rows
                        if (theClass.substr(0, 4) === "grid") {

                            gridId = theClass;

                            console.log();

                        }
                    });
                    gridUtils.getRow(gridId, 0).click();

                }
        );
    });
});
```